# How to get List of Item in DynamoDB with one hashKey and list of range key as keyCondition Expression in DynamoDB does not support IN operator

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

How to get List of Item in DynamoDB with one hashKey and list of range key  as keyCondition Expression in DynamoDB does not support IN operator.

Suppose I have table User with UserName as haskey and orderId as rangeKey
I want to get list of User with userName="sandhya" and orderId In [1,2,3]

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion and [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html). Depending on which SDK you use, you might have access to [BatchGetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html), which performs each `GetItem` in parallel. `BatchGetItem` is therefore faster if you have many items to get.